# How to scale down to 0 instances in GAE Standard Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I have a deployed a Golang app to Google Cloud Platform's App Engine Standard environment.

My app.yaml included the following lines:

```
  automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 0
  max_idle_instances: 0
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  min_instances: 0
  max_instances: 2
```

My intention was that the app should scale down to 0 instances when idle and spawn up to 2 instances to handle incoming requests.

After calling the service I noticed that it never scales down to 0 instances.

I opened the service configuration in the web console and found the following:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1
env: standard
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - url: /penguin
    script: _go_app
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_instances: 2
```

Is it possible to scale App Engine Standard services down to 0 instances? What should that look like in the yaml?

Comment: App Engine Standard scales down to 0 instances by default. If you remove the `automatic_scaling` from your `app.yaml` file and redeploy, do you still get instances spawning (like a couple of minutes after initial deployment)?

Comment: Afraid no luck. Remove "automatic_scaling:" and everything below it. Redeployed and the config now reads: 
`
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
`

It seems to default it back to automatic

Comment: I threw 1000 requests at the service an the cloud console confirms that there is one instance running. I'll wait an hour (or a few) and see if it scales to 0

Comment: It looks like there is still an instance up. However, the "Billed Instance Estimate" is currently 0. I'm hoping that this means what I think it means.

Thanks for the help @swigganicks

Comment: @swigganicks could you create that as an answer so that I can 'tick it'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

App Engine *standard environment* scales down to 0 instance by default so you shouldn't have to specify it in your app.yaml. You only need to specify the values you want to change in the automatic scaling. Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref) for a list of default scaling values under `automatic_scaling`.

After deploying, you should only have at most 1 instances showing up, but you will be billed for usage which is 0.

(Also note that this does *not* apply to a App Engine Flexible environment)

Comment: There is no default value specified for `min_idle_instances`.

Comment: @swigganicks Shouldn't you see two instances? because it's the default value.

Comment: @Ale default for flex env not standard

Comment: _  After deploying, you should only have at most 1 instances showing up, but you will be billed for usage which is 0. _ That's not the case if you are running an instance class other than F1. Anything larger than that will still result in instance hours being billed since the 28 hours free is only for an F1 instance.