# Nuxt.js on Google App Engine Standard Environment - 500 errors

Tags: express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, nuxt.js

I am serving Nuxt.js SSR application from Google App Engine, from F2 instance. All is deployed ok and works well, but sometimes I hit a weird 500 server error. I think the problem is because [GAE shuts down my instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51291372) because it is rarely used. When the instance is created again, my website fails to load (timeouts), resulting in 500 error. I am using [serverMiddleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware/) with Express.

**/server/middleware.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// this fetches a CMS token and creates a CMS object used in the request below
const CMS = require('../cms')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// get Page from the CMS
app.post('/page', async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
        let result = await CMS.getPage(req.body.route)
        res.status(200).json(result)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error', error)
    
   }
})
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs12
instance_class: F2

handlers:
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt))$
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt)$
    secure: always

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto

env_variables:
  HOST: "0.0.0.0"
  NODE_ENV: "production"

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: 1
  min_instances: 1
  max_instances: 1
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.9
  target_throughput_utilization: 0.9
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
```

And here is the relevant log screenshot:

[image: Google App Engine Log]

```
0: {
  logMessage: "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request."
  severity: "ERROR"
  time: "2022-01-14T08:55:22.057499Z"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I would not mind keeping the costs down and scaling back to 0 instances when they are not needed, but the website would still need to be served as fast as possible.

Comment: Can you expand the error and include in your question by clicking it? It seems the error is from the API.

Comment: Seems like the error is because of a timeout (21s), I've now edited the question.